# Sasl scram for the kafka 2.8 version

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing issue when performing the sasl scram implementation in the kafka 2.8 version. Plaintext was implemented successfully and scram is not working properly. creating scram credentials is working properly
but when i starting the kafka server it is starting correctly and when i try to create a topic using the kafka-topics.sh file.

it is giving the below exception
`[SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /hostaddress (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.)`

could anyone help me where i am going wrong and what i need to do and for your information i have implemented scram successfully in the kafka 1.1 version.

My configurations are as follows:

Server.properties:

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT 
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512 
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512 
advertised.host.name=localhost
```

kafka_server_jaas.conf

```
KafkaServer {
 org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
 username="admin"
 password="admin-secret";
};

Client {
 org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
 username="admin"
 password="admin-secret";
};
```

Zookeeper_jaas.conf:::

```
Server {    
 org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required   
 username="admin"   
 password="admin-secret"   
 user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

Please let me if any other configs are needed here .

Want to create a topic and try if scram is working or not. where here i am able to create the scram credentials but not able to create the topic in kafka 2.8 version.

Comment: How are you running kafka-topics?

Comment: You cannot just create the files, you need to modify `KAFKA_OPTS` to include them for each component and the CLI commands

Comment: yes i have included them in the kafka opts in the kafka-run.class and zookeeper-server-start.sh files as below

set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/Users/saikrishna.chundi/kafka-1.1.1/config/zookeeper_jaas.conf

set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/Users/saikrishna.chundi/kafka-1.1.1/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf

in this we it worked in the kafka 1.1 version i dont know why this is causing the error

Comment: I am creating kafka topics as below :

kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestTopic

Comment: @GQuintana could you help me here where i am going wrong please

Comment: Reading again your question, I noticed you are trying to use ScramLoginModule for both Application -> Kafka and Kafka -> Zookeeper authent. However, I suspect Zookeeper does not support Scram auth.